# Best way to delete all attachments in all messages in specific Mailbox

Tags: applescript

I'm total AppleScript novice and I'm trying to write a script which will delete all attachments in all messages in specified Mailbox (Mail.app).

Here is what am I trying:

```
tell application "Mail"
    tell mailbox "Sent" of account id "<XXX>"
        set ListMessage to get every message
        repeat with aMessage in ListMessage
            set aList to get every mail attachment of aMessage
            repeat with aFile in aList
                if (downloaded of aFile) then
                    delete aFile -- this gives an error
                end if
            end repeat -- next file
        end repeat -- next message
    end tell
end tell
```

Running this results in error:

`Error: the Apple Event handler failed (errAEEventFailed:-10000)`

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, that `delete` doesn’t work on mail attachments, but there is an alternative way to solve the issue: you can click the `Remove Attachments` menu item with System Events:

```
tell application "Mail"
    activate
    every item of (get selection)
end tell
tell application "System Events" to click menu item "Remove Attachments" of menu "Message" of menu bar item "Message" of menu bar 1 of process "Mail"
```